# How to use a Priority Queue with Spring boot AsyncConfigurer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, threadpoolexecutor

I have a application where I have multiple threads reading messages from a jms destination. The listener thread reads the message, makes some changes to it and calls several other methods of different classes. These methods are annotated with `@Async` annotation that all the methods gets executed in parallel using a custom `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.

```
@Override
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {        
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(corePoolSize);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(queueCapacity);
    executor.setKeepAliveSeconds(keepAliveSeconds);
    executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
    executor.setTaskDecorator(new LoggingTaskDecorator());
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

Until now all the messages were considered to be of equal priority everything was fine, as all messages were going into `LinkedBlockingQueue` if none of the `Executor` threads left available.

Now, there comes a requirement where a particular type of message read from the queue is expected to be given higher priority than any other message read from the queue.

Currently, I am using "org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor", which doesn't provide any method where I can set Priority Queue as my Blocking queue implementation.

Could, you please help me solve this scenario? 
Or is that the existing design of the system could not accommodate this change?
Or what could be the best solution to handle such scenarios?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

By simply overriding the `createQueue` method. Also you should use an `@Bean` method to create an instance of the bean, that way Spring can properly manage the lifecycle, a small but important thing (else shutdown wouldn't work properly)..

```
@Override
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
  return taskExecutor();
}        

@Bean    
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {        
  ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    protected BlockingQueue<Runnable> createQueue(int queueCapacity) {
      return new PriorityBlockingQueue<>(queueCapacity);
    } 
  };
  executor.setCorePoolSize(corePoolSize);
  executor.setMaxPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
  executor.setQueueCapacity(queueCapacity);
  executor.setKeepAliveSeconds(keepAliveSeconds);
  executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
  executor.setTaskDecorator(new LoggingTaskDecorator());  
  return executor;
}
```

Something like this should work. The `createQueue` method now creates a `PriorityBlockingQueue` instead of the default `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

Comment: This answer is incomplete. Just using a `PriorityBlockingQueue` will not help; there needs to be a way to specify the priority of a task.

Comment: It is not, as the question was on how to use a prioritized queue, which is what this answer exactly answers. It wasn't about how to specify the priority on a queue.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, it's not possible to prioritize tasks in combination with `@Async`. (The previous answer only shows how to set up a `TaskExecutor` with a priority queue, but not how to specify the priorities. On its own, that would result in `ClassCastException` because the `Runnables` used by Spring for `@Async` methods are not comparable.)

Instead, I would use an explicit `Executor`:

```
executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0, MILLISECONDS, new PriorityBlockingQueue<>());
```

Then, instead of an `@Async` method, define a regular method that submits a suitable task to this executor:

```
var task = new CustomTask(/* stuff needed to run the task and determine the priority */);
executor.execute(task);
// if the method is supposed to return a Future:
return task;
```

The last piece is a `CustomTask` class that implements `Runnable` and `Comparable`. If the method is supposed to return a `Future`, the class should implement `RunnableFuture` instead of just `Runnable`. A simple implementation could inherit from `FutureTask`:

```
class CustomTask extends FutureTask</* result type */> implements Comparable<CustomTask> {

    CustomTask(/* stuff */) {
        super(() -> /* do work */);
    }

    public int compareTo(CustomTask other) {
        /* return -1 if this task has a higher priority than the other */
    }
}
```